# How to use an embedded image of a separate assembly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, assemblies, uri, embedded-resource

there are many related questions/answers about that in SO. I took a look to some of them but none really match.

An assembly (called ResourcesLoader) holds images as **embedded ressources**.

I would like to use these pictures in another assembly.

After looking at msdn pack uri, and seeing a lots of samples, I thought that the following line would do the job :

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ResourceLoader;component/Resource Files/Bitmaps/bmp20x20/Cancel.png" />
```

Guess what? It does not work! I have checked letter by letter several times to make sure there is no mistakes.

I tried with resource images and it worked. But I have to use embedded resources...

Who can give me the magical syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the build action set on this resource?. The Build Action should be Resource instead of Embedded Resource.

Comment: Thanks, but the point of my question is to find the correct syntax working with Embedded Resource, not Resource. I have to use Embedded Resources.

Comment: Hi
From the information I got from the MCTS Training Kit book for on WPF Embedded Resources can not be accessed using the "Pack URI" syntax. 

This is what I Found in MSDN

URI resolution does not apply for URIs that refer to the following: 

Content files in referenced assemblies: these file types are not supported by WPF. 

Embedded files in referenced assemblies: URIs that identify them are unique because they include both the name of the referenced assembly and the ;component suffix. 

I think you should look for other ways to access your resource

Comment: Thanks. It's always a pain remembering whether to use Content/Resource/Embedded Resource.